# flex 3 combobox selected item

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, combobox

I have a combobox with arrayCollection dataprovider, it has nothing selected after creation. I want to add some text as first option when nothing is selected, just to indicate that the user didn't select an option yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, `prompt` property is what you are looking for. To quote the ComboBox documentation from Flex 3:

> The prompt for the ComboBox control. A prompt is a String that is displayed in the TextInput portion of the ComboBox when selectedIndex = -1. It is usually a String like "Select one...". If there is no prompt, the ComboBox control sets selectedIndex to 0 and displays the first item in the dataProvider.

Quote from [ComboBox documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#prompt)

Comment: perfect :) i didn't notice that

Comment: Hi Kalle! Currently I have no access to your `My Documents` folder, so you should either change the permissions to share this folder or correct the URL to link to Adobe's online documentation. ;-)

Comment: @splash Oops :D Thanks for the info. Removed the link.